# complex jQuery selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this jQuery selector, but I'm not getting the selection that I want. I'm trying to select `input` tags from `table:eq(0)` or `table:eq(1)` that satisfy the selector below. However, `table:eq(0)` and another random `td` element is returned.

```
table:eq(0),table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(4) input
```

I can break this selector into smaller pieces and can verify that it does return the elements I want. I just need the entire selector to be semantically correct.

I'm using this selector in a [delegated event](https://api.jquery.com/on/), which is why I'm trying to get it to work as a single selector.

**EDIT**

Here's a modified version of the selector that was suggested in the comments, but doesn't work either.

```
table:eq(0) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2) input,table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2) input
```

I'm working on getting the HTML added to this question, but there may be some sensitive information within so I'm in the process of obfuscating some of that away.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this on? BTW, the comma after `table:eq(0)` means that you're selecting `table:eq(0)` and then some other elements.

Comment: Write out the entire selector for each group **then** join them with commas

Comment: What if the "group" selector also contains commas? Do I do every combination of table->td:nth-child selector?

Comment: Commas in jQuery selectors separate elements to select. You're probably just not repeating the entire pattern you need.

Comment: Is there a better way to pass in the selector for the delegated event that I could use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard when not seeing the markup, but I think what you are after is

```
$('table:lt(2) .collection-row td:gt(1):lt(5) input')
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma seperates entire selectors so you're selecting `table:eq(0)` then `table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2)` etc. This is what I think you want:

`table:eq(0) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2) input, table:eq(0) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(3) input, table:eq(0) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(4) input, table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(2) input, table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(3) input, table:eq(1) tbody tr.collection-row td:nth-child(4) input`